# How could I manage different views for different pcs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**By default it would display like this:**

For Large Devices(Desktop >= 1200px):

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

For Medium Devices(Desktop >= 992px):

```
+----------------------+-----------------------+
|                      |                       |
+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

For Small Devices(Tables >= 786px):

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

---

**But I need like this:**

For Large Devices(Desktop >= 1200px):

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

For Medium Devices(Desktop >= 992px):

```
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|                           |                            |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

For Small Devices(Tables >= 786px):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
<article class="row-fluid">
  <section class="span4"></section>
  <section class="span4"></section>
  <section class="span4"></section>
</article>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, I guess you're using v2.3.2. Upgrade to v3.0. It already does that.

Bootstrap 2.3.2 uses `span#`, whereas Bootstrap 3.0 uses `col-xx-#`, where `xx` determines how it should display on different devices. Here's a snap from Bootstrap 3 docs:

[image]

Also, check the official [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) of Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Then how would you add classes? Could you please show as per my requirement.

Comment: I think replacing `span` with `col-lg-` would do. But you'll have to migrate your whole project to Bootstrap 3 for this.

Comment: Here's something you might find useful for that: http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/